# C# invoking class from other class

Tags: c#, websocket, sip

I am developing  a C# program that works as a websock server and controls a SIP phone (I am using the excellent voipsdk library). I am new to C# and am confused on how to integrate the two.

My Websock server class is this:

```
   public class Echo : WebSocketBehavior {


        protected override void OnMessage(MessageEventArgs e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Received message from client " + e.Data);
            Send(decode(e.Data));

        }

        protected String decode(String json) {
            var msg = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
            Console.WriteLine("\tCommand Received:" + msg.command);
            string cmd = Convert.ToString(msg.command);
            string resp = "";

            switch (cmd) {
                case "TEST":
                    Console.WriteLine("\t\tTest Invoked");
                    resp = "Testing ..";
                    break;

                case "DIAL":
                    string number = Convert.ToString(msg.number);
                    Console.WriteLine("\t\tDial:" + number);
                    resp = "Dialing " + number;
                    
                    break;

                case "HANGUP":
                    Console.WriteLine("\t\tHangup!");
                    resp = "Hanging Up";
                    break;
            }

            return (resp);
        }
    }
```

and my phone class

```
    class Phone {

        static ISoftPhone softphone;   // softphone object
        static IPhoneLine phoneLine;   // phoneline object
        static IPhoneCall call;
        static Microphone microphone;
        static Speaker speaker;
        static MediaConnector connector;
        static PhoneCallAudioSender mediaSender;
        static PhoneCallAudioReceiver mediaReceiver;

        public static void startPhone(string ext, string pwd, string host, int port) {
            softphone = SoftPhoneFactory.CreateSoftPhone(5000, 10000);

            var registrationRequired = true;

/**
            var ext = "1008";
            var pwd = "passw0rd";
            var host = "192.168.1.234";
            var port = 5060;
**/
            var account = new SIPAccount(registrationRequired, ext, ext, ext, pwd, host, port);

            RegisterAccount(account);

            microphone = Microphone.GetDefaultDevice();
            speaker = Speaker.GetDefaultDevice();
            mediaSender = new PhoneCallAudioSender();
            mediaReceiver = new PhoneCallAudioReceiver();
            connector = new MediaConnector();


        }

        static void RegisterAccount(SIPAccount account) {
            try {
                phoneLine = softphone.CreatePhoneLine(account);
                phoneLine.RegistrationStateChanged += line_RegStateChanged;
                softphone.RegisterPhoneLine(phoneLine);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine("Error during SIP registration: " + ex);
            }
        }

        static void line_RegStateChanged(object sender, RegistrationStateChangedArgs e) {
            if (e.State == RegState.NotRegistered || e.State == RegState.Error)
                Console.WriteLine("Registration failed!");

            if (e.State == RegState.RegistrationSucceeded) {
                Console.WriteLine("Registration succeeded - Online!");
                // CreateCall();
            }
        }

        public  static void CreateCall(string numberToDial) {
            // var numberToDial = "1000";
            call = softphone.CreateCallObject(phoneLine, numberToDial);
            call.CallStateChanged += call_CallStateChanged;
            call.Start();
        }

        private static void SetupDevices() {
            connector.Connect(microphone, mediaSender);
            connector.Connect(mediaReceiver, speaker);

            mediaSender.AttachToCall(call);
            mediaReceiver.AttachToCall(call);

            microphone.Start();
            speaker.Start();
        }

        static void call_CallStateChanged(object sender, CallStateChangedArgs e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Call state: {0}.", e.State);

            if (e.State == CallState.Answered)
                SetupDevices();
        }
    }
```

My problem is that I need to call the phone class from within the Websocket class in the "Protected String decode (string json) " function shown above..

How do I call the Phone class from within this function? Where do I need to declare the instance of the phone class?

Comment: I also need to send via websocket any messages I get from the phone class

Comment: Is there any reason why you declare your methodes as protected? Just make it public and off you go.

Comment: I tried to change the methods to public, but I get an error
Echo.OnMessage(MesasgeEventArgs).. cannot chaneg access modifiers whn overriding 'protected' inerited member 'WebSocketBehaviour.onMessage(MessageEventArgs)'

Comment: then you could add a public method to your class, which then invokes the protected one.

Comment: if you need to notify class A that some task was completed in class B you can do it with Event